# ¿Cómo puedo conservar los decimales?

Tags: javascript

```js
var b = "1.30";

var c = parseInt(b).toFixed(2);

console.log(c);
```

Me muestra 1.00 y no 1.30 , ¿cómo debo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Resuelto, solo deberia usar parseFloat envéz de parseInt

```js
var b = "1.30";

var c = parseFloat(b);

console.log(c);
```

Comment: De todos modos, solo tendrías que poner var b = 1.30; y js ya lo tomaria como un float, al poner las comillas lo transformas en string de manera, quizás inecesaria.